# Opening a new window in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I just started developing a PyGame. Using Python (Captain Obvious Strikes Again)

And I got my main menu all set.

It displays a text saying: Hit space when you're ready. So basicly, I want make an event that triggers and opens a new window when the user presses the spacebar key. Closing the previous window. I know there is a way of doing this, but how?

Comment: Why do you want to open a new window? Why don't you just draw in the old window?

Comment: How can I remove everything on the screen replacing it with new code then? Link to a tutorial / explanation ?

Comment: You just `fill` the screen to clear it. [link to docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) If you are unsure how to do that, perhaps you should post some of your code, or read through [an example](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp/ChimpLineByLine.html)

Comment: There are GUI libraries. The newest is [http://program.sambull.org/sgc/](GSoC http://program.sambull.org/sgc/) -- However you may be asking about stack based gameflow, if you want more than just a UI.

Answer (score 1):

To clear your window, do something like this:

```
Pseudocode:
def startGame:
    if buttonPressed = True:
        screen.fil(256, 256, 256)
    else:
        screen.blit(buttonImage, (x, y)
```

after that, draw the game or whatever itself.